# RestEasy not compatible with Jakarta RESTfull Web Services

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy

The [website of resteasy](https://resteasy.github.io/) states the following:

> Implements Jakarta RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS)

However, when I look a the [source code](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/4.7/resteasy-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/internal/ClientInvocation.java) from the last release (at this moment 4.7.1), I see that `javax.ws.rs` is still used.

We use some specific resteasy stuff in our application, so moving to Jakarta EE is impossible at this moment? Or am I missing something here? An example:

```
ClientInvocation.extractResult(new GenericType<String>(String.class), response, null);
```

So `ClientInvocation.extractResult` expects `javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType`, but I'm providing `jakarta.ws.rs.core.GenericType`.

**Update**

I'll try to explain where this question comes from.

Our current stack:

- Jboss EAP 7.3.x (~Wildfly 18)
- OpenJDK 11
- Java EE 8

We're trying to move to OpenJDK 13, but that resulted in the following exception when deploying our application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError: Signature Parse error: Expected Field Type Signature
    Remaining input: javax.transaction.Transactional$TxType
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.error(SignatureParser.java:124)
```

When I removed all `@Transactional` annotations from our application, the deploy worked again. So I assumed that `javax.transaction` is not available in OpenJDK 13, since that's the only thing I changed.

I got it working again by adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The reason I used a Jakarta dependency: `javax.transaction` didn't work, so I tried something different. I didn't try to add an extra dependency. In hindsight, that probably where I'm wrong. And since I was reading (but not really understanding) 'just replace your javax.* by jakarta.*' in several blog posts, I thought this was the way forward. I now see that I was reading blog posts about moving to Jakarta EE **9**.

Bottom line: I don't think I correctly understand the technological impact of the javax -> jakarta renaming.

Comment: What container are you targeting? [WildFly](https://wildfly.org/downloads) has WildFly Preview which is Jakarta EE 9.1 compliant.

Comment: @BalusC You are correct, I don't think I fully understand the Java EE to Jakarta EE migration. I updated my question to explain the underlying issue that led to my assumptions.